# Container port pods vs container port service

Tags: kubernetes

I would like to understand the mapping between the service port and pod container port.

Do I need to define the container port as part of my pod and also as part of my service? Or it's ok just to expose it as part of the service?

Answer (score 66):

containerPort as part of the pod definition is only informational purposes. Ultimately if you want to expose this as a service within the cluster or node then you have to create a service.

To answer your question, yes it is enough if you just expose it as part of the Kubernetes service. It is a good practice to mention as part of the pod definition so that if someone looks at the definition can understand the port where your container service is running.

This is very well explained [here](https://medium.com/faun/should-i-configure-the-ports-in-kubernetes-deployment-c6b3817e495)

Official kubernetes reference [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/workload-resources/pod-v1/#ports)

Comment: k8s website explained it as well: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/workload-resources/pod-v1/#ports "Exposing a port here gives the system additional information about the network connections a container uses, but is primarily informational. Not specifying a port here DOES NOT prevent that port from being exposed."

Comment: Thank you for pointing out. I have updated with the k8 reference link as well.

Answer (score 27):

The port that the container exposes and the port of the service are different concepts in Kubernetes.

If you want to create a service for your app, your pod has to have a port. For example, this is a pod yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-nginx
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: my-nginx
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: my-nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-nginx
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
```

containerPort sets the port that app will expose.

To access this app via a service you have to create a service object with such yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-nginx
  labels:
    run: my-nginx
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    run: my-nginx
```

In this yaml, keyword port sets the port of the service. targetPort is the port of your app. So, port of the service is different.

Here is a good definition from official doc:

> A Kubernetes Service is an abstraction which defines a logical set of
>   Pods and a policy by which to access them - sometimes called a
>   micro-service. The set of Pods targeted by a Service is (usually)
>   determined by a Label Selector (see below for why you might want a
>   Service without a selector).

Comment: Example scenario from offical doc: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/service-access-application-cluster/

Comment: containerPort does not set the port that will be exposed, it is purely informational and had no effect on Kubernetes networking. It is however good practice to document the port that the container is listening on for the next poor soul that is trying to figure out your system.

Answer (score 23):

Let's take an example and try to understand with the help of a diagram.
Consider a cluster having 2 nodes and one service. Each nodes having 2 pods and each pod having 2 containers say app container and web container.

NodePort: 30001 (cluster level exposed port for each node)

Port: 80 (service port)

targetPort:8080 (app container port same should be mentioned in docker expose)

targetPort:80 (web container port same should be mentioned in docker expose)

Now the below diagram should help us understand it better.

[image]

For reference and further details please refer to below link  https://theithollow.com/2019/02/05/kubernetes-service-publishing/

Comment: Your NodePort as a typo: missing a 0.

Comment: corrected the typo

Comment: so can I access container port by directly using the Pod's IP?

Answer (score 4):

Actually, there is one case , where pod.spec.ports[].containerPort is put to 'use' in my opinion.

I do agree with all that mostly its Informational only , considering by-design all Ports are made available from Pod.

But , if the ports[*].name is defined.
This serves a mapping for the port that can be externally addressed by service. Help to ease the port mapping.

```
$kubectl expose pod mypod --port=300 --target-port=MostfamousPort
```

Instead of Actual port-id , Port is addressed by a 'Name'

```
ports:
- containerPort: 80
  name: MostfamousPort
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though the containerPort provided in pod spec is optional and for informational purposes, one important thing about it has to be highlighted.

When a containerPort has a name specified to it as follows

```
ports:
- name: http
  containerPort: 80
- name: https
  containerPort: 443
```

I can use it in my service definition file in the targetPort. Instead of passing a number as targetPort, I can pass this name and the corresponding containerPort will get assigned as the targetPort.

So in my service definition file, I can use it like this

```
ports:
- name: name-of-service-port
  protocol: TCP
  port: port-of-service
  targetPort: http
```

So in the above snippet, the service figures out that the targetPort **http** corresponds to port 80 of the container.
You can read more about this in [Official Kubernetes Docs on Port definitions](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#field-spec-ports).